# Setting tooltip to equal content

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, tooltip

I'm trying to set a data grid's cell's tooltip to be equal to the text inside of a TextBlock in that cell. What I have so far is this:

```
<Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Grid>                         
                        <TextBlock Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" >
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" />
                            <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" />
                            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>            
    </Style>
```

However, what this does is very briefly show the tooltip and then the content in the cell is removed, so nothing shows up at all. Also, setting the tooltip from outside the Template setter is an option, but I'm not sure what the corrent binding is to do that.

Comment: Try this:  <TextBlock Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" ToolTip="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" >

Comment: This causes it to crash when you hover over a cell. It throws an InvalidOperationException: "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first."

Answer (score 1):

My example here is for a simple label but this can be applied to other controls.

```
<Label Name="lblFormName" Content="Form Elements:" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="295" >
                    <Label.ToolTip>
                        <Binding ElementName="lblFormName" Path="Content"/>
                    </Label.ToolTip>
                </Label>
```

Check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742167.aspx
or this link for a bunch of binding "how-to"s from MS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752039.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using RelativeSource? I heard of some issues about TemplateBinding vs. RelativeSource ([WPF TemplateBinding vs RelativeSource TemplatedParent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131222/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent)).

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YourAncestorType}, AncestorLevel=1},Path=Content}" />
```

Where "YourAncestorType" is the type of the parent you want to find.

Or you could also try the same approach with

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" />
```

See also: http://www.wpfwiki.com/Default.aspx?Page=WPF%20Q5.3&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: The first method just creates empty tooltips. I tried setting the ancestor to TextBlock and DataGridCell. Also I put the path to Text and Content.

The second method causes the cells to disappear again and the tooltips flash breifly.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the ToolTip from the ControlTemplate and defining a separate Setter in the Style for the Tooltip.

Here is the XAML using your sample:

```
<Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type WpfToolkit:DataGridCell}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="WpfToolkit:DataGridCell">
        <Grid>
          <TextBlock Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TextWrapping="Wrap" > 
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" /> 
            <!--<TextBlock.ToolTip> 
              <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" /> 
            </TextBlock.ToolTip>-->
          </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content.Text}"/>
</Style>
```