# In WPF, what is a TemplatedParent?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to understand RelativeSource binding but I can't find a definition for TemplatedParent.
[MSDN says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.templatedparent%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

> "Gets a static value that is used to return a RelativeSource constructed for the TemplatedParent mode."

It doesn't appear in the index of "Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed".

Simply, what is a TemplatedParent please?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131222/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`TemplatedParent` refers to the `Control` instance that the template is being applied to. You can use `TemplatedParent` to bind to properties declared on that object (and its base classes).

Comment: So if I had a TextBox inside a StackPanel inside a DataTemplate of an ItemsControl, the TemplatedParent of the TextBox would be the ItemsControl not the StackPanel?

Comment: @David: The `TemplatedParent` for an item in an `ItemsControl` is neither of the ones you think. I believe it's a `ContentPresenter` instance (a separate one for each item in your `ItemsSource`).

Comment: Hmm, thanks Gabe, but I think I'm lost again. ConentPresenter is not in the index of "WPF Unleashed", I'll have to do some more searching...

Comment: @David: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx for all the gory details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this explanation. I was just wondering if there's a difference with {RelativeSource Self} ?

Answer (score 8):

In WPF, a template is what it uses to construct the tree of a type.  WPF essentially makes a copy of the template when a new object of that type is created.

As a result, *inside* the template, if you want to refer to the new object, you use `TemplatedParent` for quick access.  Otherwise, you'll have to use `RelativeSource` to walk the tree upwards to find the parent object.

Answer (score -1):

Notice:

TemplatedParent means Parent is Templated. Templated is passive voice in English. In other words, the parent element is applied with a Template. So in the template you can binding the parent's property easily.