# Change XAML ControlTemplate Child Elements Attributes during Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbFoo" Text="LOREM IPSUM" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

Is there a way to change the text of `tbFoo` during runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Bind the property to some property of the [`TemplatedParent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5294699/643085):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbFoo" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then:

```
<Window Title="My Window"/>
```

will cause the `tbFoo` to have the "My Window" text.

**Option 2:** Use [`Triggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.triggers.aspx):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbFoo"/>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsActive" Value="True">
          <Setter TargetName="tbFoo" Property="Text" Value="Window is Active!"/>
       </Trigger>
       <Trigger Property="IsActive" Value="False">
          <Setter TargetName="tbFoo" Property="Text" Value="Window is Inactive!"/>
       </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: What a simple solution. How can I not think of `TemplateBinding`? Thanks anyway.