# Binding IsExpanded to templatedParent in the TreeViewItem style not working

Tags: wpf, treeviewitem

the following works which is within treeview

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
<Setter Property="IsExpanded" 
      Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

this doesnt as it is in the different resource as treeviewItem style

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" Style="{StaticResource TreeViewExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Please let me know where am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

The wrong this seems to bee that you are missing something. The `TemplatedParent` is refers to the `Control` instance that the template is being applied to, and not to its `DataContext`. Check [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294611/in-wpf-what-is-a-templatedparent). A simple solution should be make the binding to its `DataContext`:

```
IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Hope helps...