# Limitations of TemplateBinding

Tags: wpf, templatebinding

A custom control (written under VS 2008) has a SelectedColor Dependency Property and its Control Template contains the following:

```xml
...
<Rectangle>
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{TemplateBinding SelectedColor}"/>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
...
```

The rectangle does not have the correct color unless the binding is repleaced with:

```xml
...
<Rectangle>
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding SelectedColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
...
```

OK, I am aware that TemplateBinding is a simplified version of Binding and it has a set of limitations, so what is the exact limitation that cause the above code not to work?

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx) those are 2 analogous notations. Did you try with explicit `Path=`

Comment: I've run into this before, too. I never could figure out the specific differences apart from `TemplateBinding` not supporting nested paths. So I just use `TemplateBinding` by default (better performance) and switch to `Binding` if it doesn't work. Annoying, but that's my process.

Comment: @Philippe Lavoie - The problem lies in the use of TemplateBinding, other notation fails as well.

Comment: The difference between both notations is that TemplateBinding is processed at compiletime and the Binding with a relative source at runtime. You can have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131222/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent

Though this doesn't explain your problem.

Answer (score 2):

TemplateBinding are very different. Think of them as simple value assignment when the template is applied.
Since you SelectedItem changes at runtime, you need a real binding for property change notification.