# TemplateBinding to RowDefinition.Height ignored in ContentControl

Tags: silverlight, grid, dependency-properties, contentcontrol, templatebinding

**Description:** 
I have a custom content control and I am trying to enable some external settings via dependency properties. Basically it's a decorator panel with two grid rows, upper one is the header, the lower one is the content (via `ContentPresenter`).

There are 3 items that are bound to the template (via TemplateBinding), `HeaderHeight`, `TextSize` and `Header` (each of them has its dependency property of an appropriate type).

**Problem:**
While two of the bindings work perfectly (even in design-time), the third one does not. The `FontSize="{TemplateBinding TextSize}"` and the `Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"` bindings work, but the `<RowDefinition Height="{TemplateBinding HeaderHeight}" />` **does not work**.

The grid splits the rows' heights 50/50, no matter which value I set the HeaderHeight property to. It does not even take the default value from the DP metadata.

**Question:**
What is the problem with this scenario? Why do the other two bindings work with no problems and this one behaves as if there is no binding at all?

**Note:**
If I set `DataContext = this` in the constructor and replace `{TemplateBinding HeaderHeight}` with `{Binding HeaderHeight}`, the problem disappears and it works as intended. But I'd like to know why I don't need to do the same thing with other bindings to make them work.

**XAML (Themes/Generic.xaml):**

```
<Style TargetType="local:KaiPanel">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:KaiPanel">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="{TemplateBinding HeaderHeight}" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Border>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="{TemplateBinding TextSize}" 
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Border>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Content Control (C#):**

```
public class KaiPanel : ContentControl
{
    public KaiPanel()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(KaiPanel);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextSize", typeof(double), typeof(KaiPanel), new PropertyMetadata(15.0));

    public double TextSize
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(TextSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(String), typeof(KaiPanel), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public String Header
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderHeight", typeof(GridLength), typeof(KaiPanel), new PropertyMetadata(new GridLength(40)));

    public GridLength HeaderHeight
    {
        get { return (GridLength)GetValue(HeaderHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderHeightProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Custom Control usage (XAML):**

```
<UserControl ...>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="buttonsStackPanel" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <!-- Some buttons here -->
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <controls:KaiPanel x:Name="contentPanel">
                <navigation:Frame x:Name="contentFrame" Source="KP">
                    <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
                        <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                            <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="KP" MappedUri="/Views/Kornelijepetak.xaml" />
                            <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="KAI" MappedUri="/Views/KaiNetwork.xaml" />
                        </uriMapper:UriMapper>
                    </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
                </navigation:Frame>
            </controls:KaiPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your Xaml actually using the KaiPanel so we can reproduce the problem? So far everything shown look OK, but it only takes one little detail to break something.

Comment: @I have updated the code, but it doesn't matter. It doesn't work even if you place a single <controls:KaiPanel /> tag. It should take the default value from the DP, but it doesn't. Tried to place different content inside, but it doesn't matter - it always behave the same: 50/50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly it seems what you're attempting to do requires more than just a single data binding.  [RowDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) isn't a subclass of FrameworkElement, and it doesn't match any of the other criteria specified in the [MSDN Silverlight data binding documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28VS.95%29.aspx), so it can't be used as the target of a binding.

What you want to do is possible, but unfortunately it involves a little more code.

Firstly, add a field for the main grid (I've called it `mainGrid`) to your `KaiPanel` class.  Then, override the `OnApplyTemplate` method in this class to grab the main `Grid` from the template and keep a reference to it in your `mainGrid` field:

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        mainGrid = GetTemplateChild("LayoutRoot") as Grid;
        SetHeaderRowHeight();
    }
```

This calls a method that updates the height of the first row of the grid.  That method is as follows:

```
    private void SetHeaderRowHeight()
    {
        if (mainGrid != null)
        {
            mainGrid.RowDefinitions[0].Height = HeaderHeight;
        }
    }
```

I admit I'm not 100% sure that `OnApplyTemplate` is called after the DPs are set.  It seems that this is the case (a quick test seemed to confirm this), but all I could find to back this up was [this post on the Silverlight forums](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/53483/139907.aspx#138831).  If you find that this isn't the case, you'll need to register a PropertyChangedCallback on the `HeaderHeight` DP that will also call this `SetHeaderRowHeight` method.

See also http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/76992.aspx#183089.

Comment: You say that it can't be used in binding, yet it works in a normal binding (not TemplateBinding). Check my Note again. If DataContext=this is set in a constructor, and in template if I set: {Binding HeaderHeight} instead of {TemplateBinding HeaderHeight}, then it works. Very strange behaviour. I have another control that even works with TemplateBinding, which makes this even more strange.

Comment: Correction: I have now looked at my other control. It doesn't work with template binding, but it does with normal binding (with DataContext set to the control itself).

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeSource and TemplatedParent instead:

```
<RowDefinition Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
 Path=HeaderHeight}" />
```

Here the difference between TemplateBinding and RelativeSource TemplatedParent is explained:
[WPF TemplateBinding vs RelativeSource TemplatedParent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131222/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent)