# TemplateBinding does not work for SelectedItem in custom control extending ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, templatebinding

We've created a custom ComboBox control that has a button to clear the ComboBox's selection:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ClearableComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="SelectedItem" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ClearableComboBox}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <DockPanel>
                        <Button Name="btnClear" DockPanel.Dock="Right" ToolTip="Clear" Width="20">
                            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/img/icons/silk/cross.png" Stretch="None" />
                        </Button>
                        <ComboBox Name="comboBox"
                                  ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                                  SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The binding for ItemsSource works fine, however the binding for SelectedItem does not. After searching on Google, I found the solution to the problem [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/5e29dd2f-9fa6-4b28-8d90-5a7384525ce5). Specifically, changing the SelectedItem binding to

`SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedItem}"`

makes it work as expected.

Why doesn't the original TemplateBinding on SelectedItem work, while the TemplateBinding for ItemsSource worked just fine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the differences (which, as I think, is the main problem in your case) is that `TemplateBinding` is always `OneWay`, whereas `Binding` chooses to be `OneWay` or `TwoWay` [depending on the property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.bindstwowaybydefault.aspx). (More details [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/10/19/wpf-basic-data-binding-faq.aspx).)

You may find other differences at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131222/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent).