# When to use TemplateBinding and TemplatedParent in WPF

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, controltemplate

I have a confusion over TemplateBinding and TemplatedParent. I have gone through this link also
[WPF TemplateBinding vs RelativeSource TemplatedParent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131222/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent)

But my doubt is when to use TemplateBinding and TemplatedParent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`{TemplateBinding X}` is simply a shortcut way of writing the `{Binding X, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}`.

They evaluate to the same thing, although `TemplateBinding` is evaluated at compile-time while `RelativeSource TemplatedParent` is evaluated at run-time.

Because it is evaluated at compile-time, `TemplateBinding` is a bit faster to evaluate however it will throw errors if it doesn't think the bound property exists. If you know the property exists but the compiler doesn't know about it, then you use `RelativeSource TemplatedParent` since it is evaluated at run-time instead of compile-time.

To summarize, use `TemplateBinding` unless it gives you an error and you know the property exists. Then use `RelativeSource TemplatedParent`

The [accepted answer to the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823547/302677) contains a pretty good summary on the differences between the two

Comment: `TemplateBinding` is `OneWay` and `TemplatedParent` is `TwoWay`.