# How can I bind to the Center property of an EllipseGeometry?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am trying to move an Ellipse around inside of a custom control, and I care about it's center point so I am using `EllipseGeometry` inside of a `Path` instead of using `Ellipse` on its own.

So I created this custom control (CenterPoint is harded coded to 100,100):

```
Public Class RippleButton
  Inherits ButtonBase

    Shared Sub New()
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(GetType(RippleButton), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(GetType(RippleButton)))
  End Sub

  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()

    CenterPoint = New Point(100, 100)
  End Sub


  Public Property CenterPoint As Point
    Get
      Return DirectCast(GetValue(CenterPointProperty), Point)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Point)
      SetValue(CenterPointProperty, value)
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Shared ReadOnly CenterPointProperty As DependencyProperty = 
                         DependencyProperty.Register("CenterPoint", _
                         GetType(Point), GetType(RippleButton))

End Class
```

The default style for this class (EllipseGeometry's Center is bound to CenterPoint in the control):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:RippleButton}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:RippleButton}">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <Path Fill="Red" ClipToBounds="True">
            <Path.Data>
              <EllipseGeometry Center="{TemplateBinding CenterPoint}"
                               RadiusX="100"
                               RadiusY="100" />
            </Path.Data>
          </Path>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

When put my RippleButton on a WPF window, the red ellipse is always in the top left corner instead of 100,100. What is going on here and how do I get it to move to the CenterPoint that is defined in the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why exactly it won't work with a `TemplateBinding`, but you could replace that with a regular binding:

```
<EllipseGeometry
    Center="{Binding CenterPoint, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
    RadiusX="100" RadiusY="100" />
```

Comment: Well, I don't know what the difference is, but this works. Accepted. Hopefully someone will be able to explain why TemplateBinding doesn't work there though.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9161283/1136211) for the difference between TemplateBinding and regular Binding with TemplatedParent. However, that does not explain why the TemplateBinding isn't working here.