# Why does data binding my chart series color fail?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, charts, .net-4.5, wpftoolkit

I am drawing simple line charts using the WPF toolkit. My goal is to set the line color of my series via Data Binding. This succeeds only *partially*. The question is: why?

**Setup**

Namespaces:

```
xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit" x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
xmlns:media="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Media;assembly=PresentationCore"
```

Chart:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="chart">
    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries x:Name="seriesEntries" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" DataPointStyle="{StaticResource CommonLineSeriesDataPoint}">
        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Tag>
            <media:Brush>Green</media:Brush>
        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.Tag>
    </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Ignore the `Tag` for now, it will be relevant later.

Notice the chart has a custom data point style, `CommonLineSeriesDataPoint`:

```
<Style x:Key="CommonLineSeriesDataPoint" TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <media:Brush>Red</media:Brush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineSeries">
    <Setter Property="DataPointStyle" Value="{StaticResource CommonLineSeriesDataPoint}" />
</Style>
```

As expected, this colors my line series **red**:

[image: Red line series]

**Breaking Change**

Now I want to data bind my data point background. I make only one change. Instead of specifying the background brush directly, I bind it to the `Tag` property of my `LineSeries`, which is also a brush (see previous `LineSeries` declaration, it's a **green** one).

```
<Style x:Key="CommonLineSeriesDataPoint" TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineDataPoint">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type chartingToolkit:LineSeries}}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineSeries">
    <Setter Property="DataPointStyle" Value="{StaticResource CommonLineSeriesDataPoint}" />
</Style>
```

The result is this:

[image]

So the dots are green. *But the line is gone*.

My expectation is to see a green line as well! Where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after digging in the WPF Toolkit Sources.

Turns out the `Stroke` property of the series' `Polyline` is bound to a `Background` property via `TemplateBinding`. I suspect this doesn't go well with my try binding the `Background` property itself.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823547/56658) on SO suggests that `TemplateBinding` is evaluated at compile time. So let's get rid of the TemplateBinding and bind the `Stroke` property directly to the `Tag` of my `LineSeries` (remember: the `Tag` contains the **green** brush).

From the WPF Toolkit Source **\Source\DataVisualization\Themes\generic.xaml** I copied part of the style definition for the `LineSeries` and added it to my `ResourceDictionary`:

```
<Style x:Key="CommonLineSeries" TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineSeries" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type chartingToolkit:LineSeries}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="chartingToolkit:LineSeries">
                <Canvas x:Name="PlotArea">
                    <Polyline Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" Stroke="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type chartingToolkit:LineSeries}}}" Style="{TemplateBinding PolylineStyle}"/>
                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

(If interested you can search for `<!--  charting:LineSeries  -->` in **generic.xaml** to find the source I copied from.)

The only thing I modified is the binding of `Stroke`. Here I use the same binding I used for my data points.

Last thing to do: tell the `LineSeries` to use this style:

```
<chartingToolkit:LineSeries x:Name="seriesEntries" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" DataPointStyle="{StaticResource CommonLineSeriesDataPoint}" Style="{StaticResource CommonLineSeries}">
```

And lo and behold, it works. The line is back and it's green:

[image: Diagram - Line Color Fixed]

(If you look closely you see that the legend entry for the series still has the wrong color. But I assume the solution will be quite similar to the above.)