# What do "TemplatedParent template properties" meant in dependency property precedence

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, controltemplate

I am new to WPF, so forgive me if my question sounds silly.

As mentioned in [list of sources for dependency property values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing), For point 4 what do "TemplatedParent template properties" meant?

For e.g if If I create a button which has control template define against its "template" property. Does this "template" is what meant in point 4 of link? Or it means properties of child control created within control?

Answer (score 0):

TemplatedParent refers to the Control instance that the template is being applied to. You can use TemplatedParent to bind to properties declared on that object (and its base classes).This is helpful to understand [TemplateBinding Vs TemplatedParent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131222/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent)