# Accessing element attribute value from its template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a combobox defined in xaml:

```
<ComboBox Width="100"/>
```

This ComboBox, along with all other combobxes I have, is styled with a ControlTemplate which I copied and edited some colors and such in it.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">....
```

In this control template, how can I access the value of the Width attribute from the element above?

So for example:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
     <Grid Width="??{Binding WidthValue}??" >....
```

Where the {Binding WidthValue} is 100, from the Width="100" above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
```

P.S. you'll often see this used in the default control templates for controls for attributes like `Padding`, `Margin`, and `SnapsToDevicePixels`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TemplatedParent` binding

```
<Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Width}">
```

but you shouldn't need to as `Grid` should stretch so if you limit `ComboBox` to 100 you should automatically limit `Grid` inside

**EDIT**

If you need to bind to width then I would suggest to bind to `ActualWidth` instead of `Width`

```
<Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}">
```

as `Width` does not need to be defined in all controls where this template is used

Comment: I went with the shorter solution above and used Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" and it works exactly like I wanted, thanks. What is the difference between the short one and the longer one anyway?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131222/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent) question