# TextBox Customization Malfunction

Tags: c#, wpf

I needed to create a textBoox that completely blends with the background so I used this XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="Hello" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="txtAsk" FontFamily="Consolas" Margin="8,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" AutoWordSelection="True" KeyDown="onEnter">
                <TextBox.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle  Stroke="{StaticResource ResourceKey=detailMarkBrush}" StrokeThickness="0"/>
                            <TextBox Margin="4" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" BorderThickness="0" Background="{x:Null}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </TextBox.Template>               
            </TextBox>
```

However, now the problem is, when I attached a button to the interface and triggered it to show the content of the TextBox in a message window, it only shows the default text even after changing the value inside the text box! 
The button code is as follows:

```
private void btnTriggerEnter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(txtAsk.Text);
        }
```

I am not sure where I screwed up. Please comment if any other detail is required.
My MainWindow has this code:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);         
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text}"
```

That's because `TemplateBinding` only gives you a `OneWay` source (in the underlying `Binding`), you need `TwoWay`.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/liviuc/archive/2009/12/14/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent.aspx
- [WPF TemplateBinding vs RelativeSource TemplatedParent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131222/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent)