# Custom Control Foreground in ContentPresenter

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls, controltemplate, attached-properties

I have a custom control that is really just there for type-specific template selection:

```
public class MyControl : Control { }
```

I then have a template that is auto-applied:

```
<Style TargetType="MyControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="MyControl">
                <Path Data="..." Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

That works fine, I can drop a  into the XAML and it shows properly.

My problem is trying to get the Foreground to show correctly when this is in a content presenter.  Consider the following content presenter:

```
<ContentPresenter Control.Foreground="Red" Content="This Works"/>
```

The text shown is red.  But if I make the content be a "MyControl", it doesn't - it goes up the visual tree looking for a foreground to inherit.  It seems to ignore Control.Foreground.  How do I get my custom control to pay attention to Control.Foreground on the content presenter?

In case it matters, this content presenter is in a control template for a TabItem, trying to get one of these "MyControl" instances to be used as a the header of the TabItem.

Comment: What happens when you use named style instead?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean for the Style that I posted.  That style is getting applied - the path is rendered correctly.  It just is not the right color.

Comment: What I have read there seems to be an issue when working with `TemplateBinding`, Have you tried `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Foreground}` in your `Style`?
[Here is a link with explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9460574/2029607)

Comment: I just tried that, it did not fix the problem.  I was able to bypass the problem by using a style to handle the coloring instead of the template.  Still don't know why the control template approach doesn't work.